# string.compare and string for comparison

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have my code like this

```
private void btnStartAnalysis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

            {

        //Checks for the selectedItem in the cmbOpearions dropdown and make call to appropriate functions.
        if((string) (cmbOperations.SelectedItem) == "PrimaryKeyTables")
            {
            //This is the function call for the primary key checking in DB
            GetPrimaryKeyTable();
            }

        //Checks for the selectedItem in the cmbOpearions dropdown and make call to appropriate functions.
        if((string) (cmbOperations.SelectedItem) == "NonPrimaryKeyTables")
            {
            //This is the function call for the nonPrimary key checking in DB
            GetNonPrimaryKeyTables();
            }

        //Checks for the selectedItem in the cmbOpearions dropdown and make call to appropriate functions.
        if((string) (cmbOperations.SelectedItem) == "ForeignKeyTables")
            {
            //This is the function call for the nonPrimary key checking in DB
            GetForeignKeyTables();
            }

        //Checks for the selectedItem in the cmbOpearions dropdown and make call to appropriate functions.
        if((string) (cmbOperations.SelectedItem) == "NonForeignKeyTables")
            {
            //This is the function call for the nonPrimary key checking in DB
            GetNonForeignKeyTables();
            }

        if((string) (cmbOperations.SelectedItem) == "UPPERCASEDTables")
            {
            //This is the function call for the nonPrimary key checking in DB
            GetTablesWithUpperCaseName();
            }

        if((string) (cmbOperations.SelectedItem) == "lowercasedtables")
            {
            //This is the function call for the nonPrimary key checking in DB
            GetTablesWithLowerCaseName();
            }
        }
```

But here using (string) makes problem in case sensitiveness.So I want to use string.comapare in place of (string).

Can anybody give me any hint how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
if (string.Compare((string) cmbOperations.SelectedItem, 
        "NonForeignKeyTables", true) == 0) // 0 result means same
    GetNonForeignKeyTables();
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use:

```
// There's no point in casting it in every if statement
string selectedItem = (string) cmbOperations.SelectedItem;

if (selectedItem.Equals("NonPrimaryKeyTables",
                        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    ...
}
```

Choosing the right string comparison can be tricky. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919) for a lot more information.

I *wouldn't* suggest using `Compare` as other people have suggested, simply because it's not the right emphasis - `Compare` is designed to be used for testing which order strings should appear in when they're sorted. That has the by-product of allowing you to test for equality, but it's not the main aim. Using `Equals` shows that all you care about is equality - if the two strings aren't equal, you don't care which would come first. Using `Compare` would *work*, but it doesn't leave your code expressing itself as clearly as it can.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.string.compare%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) have really good explanation about the string.compare method..
you just have to write

```
String.Compare (String, String)
```

to compare your strings.. used with a Switch-case instruction it will be ok..

Use

```
String.Compare (String, String, boolean)
```

To set the case comparaison

Comment: See my answer for why I wouldn't use `Compare`. Also it's not clear how switch/case is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive comparison:

```
    string a = "text1";
    string b = "TeXt1";

    if(string.Compare( a, b, true ) == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Equal");
    }
```